# How to pass variable to javascript function through cq.ext.button handler?

Tags: extjs, aem

I have the following code in my CQ `dialog.xml`

```
<toolbar
jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
xtype="toolbar">
<items
    jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
    <input
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="textfield"
        name="./myInput">
    </input>
    <button
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="button"
        name="./myButton"
        text="Submit" handler ="function() {passMyInput()};">
    </button>
</items>
```

I have implemented the function `passMyInput()` as follow:

```
passMyInput(){ alert("test");}
```

This works fine. My question is how to pass the value of `./myInput` to the `function passMyInput` ?

I have tried `handler ="function() passMyInput('./myInput')};"` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button's handler function receves 2 arguments, button `b` and eventObject `e`.

We can obtain the container dialog through the button and then use the `getField()` method to obtain the value of the field.

The modified hander function would be

```
function(b, e) {
    var dlg = b.findParentByType('dialog');
    var val = dlg.getField('./myInput').getValue();
    passMyInput(val);
}
```

For more info, refer [widget docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.Button)