# how to pass string to cq dialog textfield

Tags: aem

In `cq dialog.xml` I have the following `textfield`:

```
<foo
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        name="./foo"
                        xtype="textfield"/>
```

In javascript, I have the following code:

```
function baar(){ var myString = "test";}
```

How to pass `myString` to the `cq Dialog textfield`?

Comment: When is the function getting invoked? Why do you want to pass the value to dialog? Please provide additional details.

Comment: Yes when baar() is called. When someone typed invalid text into foo textfield, he can click on some button near this textfield and the function baar() is called. In should write the valid text into the textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setValue()` method of the field to set the value.

```
function baar() {
    var myString = "test";
    var foo = this.findParentByType('dialog').getField('./foo');'
    foo.setValue(myString);
}
```

Kindly refer the [widget api docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.Button) for more information on the available methods. A similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652112/how-to-pass-variable-to-javascript-function-through-cq-ext-button-handler/24653107#24653107) already answers this.